# Depth-first search terminating early

Tags: java, algorithm, search, graph, path-finding

I'm creating a program in Java that solves the [n-puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-puzzle),  without using heuristics, simply just with depth-first and breadth-first searches of the state space. I'm struggling a little bit with my implementation of depth-first search. Sometimes it will solve the given puzzle, but other times it seems to give up early.

Here's my DFS class. DepthFirstSearch() is passed a PuzzleBoard, which is initially generated by shuffling a solved board (to ensure that the board is in a solvable state).

```
public class DepthFirst {
static HashSet<PuzzleBoard> usedStates = new HashSet<PuzzleBoard>(); 

public static void DepthFirstSearch(PuzzleBoard currentBoard)
{   
    // If the current state is the goal, stop.
    if (PuzzleSolver.isGoal(currentBoard)) {    
        System.out.println("Solved!");
        System.exit(0); 
    } 

    // If we haven't encountered the state before,
    // attempt to find a solution from that point.
    if (!usedStates.contains(currentBoard)) {                       
        usedStates.add(currentBoard);           
        PuzzleSolver.print(currentBoard);

        if (PuzzleSolver.blankCoordinates(currentBoard)[1] != 0) {
            System.out.println("Moving left");
            DepthFirstSearch(PuzzleSolver.moveLeft(currentBoard));
        }
        if (PuzzleSolver.blankCoordinates(currentBoard)[0] != PuzzleSolver.n-1) {
            System.out.println("Moving down");
            DepthFirstSearch(PuzzleSolver.moveDown(currentBoard)); 
        }
        if (PuzzleSolver.blankCoordinates(currentBoard)[1] != PuzzleSolver.n-1) {
            System.out.println("Moving right");
            DepthFirstSearch(PuzzleSolver.moveRight(currentBoard)); 
        }
        if (PuzzleSolver.blankCoordinates(currentBoard)[0] != 0) {
            System.out.println("Moving up");
            DepthFirstSearch(PuzzleSolver.moveUp(currentBoard));    
        }

        return; 
    } else {
        // Move up a level in the recursive calls
        return; 
    }
}   
}
```

I can assert that my moveUp(), moveLeft(), moveRight(), and moveDown() methods and logic work correctly, so the problem must lie somewhere else.

Here's my PuzzleBoard object class with the hashCode and equals methods:

```
static class PuzzleBoard {
    short[][] state;        
    /**
     * Default constructor for a board of size n
     * @param n Size of the board 
     */
    public PuzzleBoard(short n) {
        state = PuzzleSolver.getGoalState(n);
    }
    public PuzzleBoard(short n, short[][] initialState) {
        state = initialState; 
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Arrays.deepHashCode(state);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        PuzzleBoard other = (PuzzleBoard) obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (state[i][j] != other.state[i][j])
                    return false; 
            }
        }
        return true;
    }   
}
```

As previously stated, sometimes the search works properly and finds a path to the solution, but other times it stops before it finds a solution and before it runs out of memory.

Here is a snippet of the output, beginning a few moves before the search stops searching.

```
...
Moving down
6 1 3 
5 8 2 
0 7 4 
Moving right
6 1 3 
5 8 2 
7 0 4 
Moving left
Moving right
Moving up
6 1 3 
5 0 2 
7 8 4 
Moving left
Moving down
Moving right
Moving up
Moving up
Moving right
Moving down
Moving up
Moving down
Moving up
Moving down
Moving up
Moving down
Moving up
Moving down
...
```

I truncated it early for brevity, but it ends up just moving up and down dozens of times and never hits the solved state.

Can anyone shed light on what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**: Here is MoveUp(). The rest of the move methods are implemented in the same way.

```
/**
 * Move the blank space up
 * @return The new state of the board after the move
 */
static PuzzleBoard moveUp(PuzzleBoard currentState) {
    short[][] newState = currentState.state; 
        short col = blankCoordinates(currentState)[0]; 
        short row = blankCoordinates(currentState)[1]; 
        short targetCol = col; 
        short targetRow = row; 
        newState[targetCol][targetRow] = currentState.state[col - 1][row];
        newState[targetCol - 1][targetRow] = 0; 

        return new PuzzleBoard(n, newState); 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it generates a solvable puzzle?

Comment: The way I'm generating my puzzle to solve is by starting from a solved state and then making a random number of valid moves from there. So yes, I am starting from a solvable state.

Comment: Just a guess since I don't quite understand the if() statements to determine which direction to move; but I get the feeling it is getting "stuck" in a corner. Since you are using `if()` and no `else if()` it may be trying to move up and then immediately moved back down. Then tries to move up again?

Comment: Where is the `PuzzleSolver` code?

Comment: The move sequence `Moving up, Moving down` should be invalid, because it leads to the previous state. You should check you `equals` method if it really works as expected (and also your `hashCode()` method). Write some tests for them...

Comment: @MrSmith42 no Moving up & down are valid moves as you do not know from which previous state the current state has come up and i think the only way is check it in hashset which OP has done.

Comment: @Michelle is PuzzleSolver.moveLeft(Current) and other such statements generating new board object or just changing old one?. It must return a new object ideally else the DFS will not work correctly in this implementation.

Comment: @VikramBhat she checks in equals() for that: if (this == obj){return true;}. Also, she mentioned that sometimes her DFS finds the solution correctly, so I'd assume that's not the problem.

Comment: @VikramBhat I added one of the move() functions from the PuzzleSolver class for more context.

Comment: @Michelle Please try what i have mentioned in my answer as your rest of logic seems right just have doubts with hashcode & equals. You donot need them if do as i have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have had many problems with hashset in the past best thing to try is not to store object in hashset but try to encode your object into string.

Here is a way to do it:-

```
StringBuffer encode(PuzzleBoard b) {

   StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i=0;i<b.n;i++) {

      for(int j=0;j<b.n;j++) {

          // "," is used as separator
            buff.append(","+b.state[i][j]);

      }
   }
   return buff;
}

Make two changes in the code:-

if(!usedStates.contains(encode(currentBoard))) {

usedStates.add(encode(currentBoard));
......

}
```

**Note:-** Here no need to write your own hashcode function & also no need to implement equals function as java has done it for you in StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

I got one of the problems in your implementation:-

In th following code:-

```
static PuzzleBoard moveUp(PuzzleBoard currentState) {
    short[][] newState = currentState.state; 
        short col = blankCoordinates(currentState)[0]; 
        short row = blankCoordinates(currentState)[1]; 
        short targetCol = col; 
        short targetRow = row; 
        newState[targetCol][targetRow] = currentState.state[col - 1][row];
        newState[targetCol - 1][targetRow] = 0; 

        return new PuzzleBoard(n, newState); 
    }
```

Here you are using the reference of same array as newState from currentState.state so when you make changes to newState your currentState.state will also change which will affect DFS when the call returns. To prevent that you should initialize a new array. Heres what to be done:-

```
static PuzzleBoard moveUp(PuzzleBoard currentState) {
    short[][] newState = new short[n][n]; 
        short col = blankCoordinates(currentState)[0]; 
        short row = blankCoordinates(currentState)[1]; 
        short targetCol = col; 
        short targetRow = row; 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {

          for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {

               newState[i][j] = currentState.state[i][j];
           }

        }
        newState[targetCol][targetRow] = currentState.state[col - 1][row];
        newState[targetCol - 1][targetRow] = 0; 

        return new PuzzleBoard(n, newState); 
    }
```

Do this change for all moveup,movedown....

Moreover I donot think your hashset is working properly because if it was then you would always find your new state in hashset and your program would stop. As in equals you comparing the state arrays with same reference hence will always get true. Please try and use my encode function as hash.